# Php Mass/group check for values

Tags: php

I'm building a form (fun) and obviously those can get tedious and as i sit here writing validation functions I'm wondering...

Say for example I have 3 fields**(name,lastname,age)**

The variables are

```
$fname = $_POST['name'];
$lname = $POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

And say I want to check for empties, id

```
if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($age)){
//do something
}
```

Is there a way to make this more manageable? Because say that now, instead of 3 fields in the form, I have 100...it get quite unruly fast

So is there a way I can check en-mass ?

Comment: How did you design your form to have `100 fields` why not make it a wizard ???

Answer (score 2):

```
$required_fields = array("name", "address", "phone", "email");
foreach ($require_fields as $field) {
    if (!strlen($_POST[$field])) {
        echo "$field cannot be empty";
    }
}
```

EDIT:
You Can get the $_POST array by

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $name) {
            $required_fields[] = "$key=$name";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i was thinking about something like this but, again say i had 100 variables for the form(random number) then id still have to manually enter the variables into the array. Lazy i know but..i figure less code is better? lol thanks

Answer (score 1):

`if(empty($_POST)){..}else{...}` will give you result, depending on,  **If more than one value is set; or no value is set at-all.** Sort of like True/False.

But, you must **not** include a `value=''` for the "Submit Button" itself, otherwise, it will give you a True result, all the time. Because the `$_POST` global, checks the value of the submit button too.
or, you can deduct one value from your query. Optionally you can debug values by `var_dump($_POST)`

If you want to check, "at-least one field is not empty" then,

```
if(count($_POST) !=0){
   echo ' at least one value is set';}
else {echo 'no value is set';}
```

will check, if there is at-least, one item submitted.

Comment: This would only check if no fields are sent.
@somdow wanted to check if at least one was empty.

See || in his original if statement.

EDIT: Nevermind, just seen your edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check them all, do something along the lines of.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){

   foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
      if(empty($val)){
          // An empty field exists. Your action here.
      }
   }
}
```

Although it's worth noting that if you have checkbox's on your page which aren't ticked, an empty $_POST entry won't get send back, it just won't exist at all.

So you'll need to check checkbox's with an if statement.

For example, the checkbox name is 'agree'

```
if(!isset($_POST['agree'])){
   // Checkbox not ticked.
}
```

Comment: Does this apply to pulldowns also? or only checkboxes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check each post key

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)!=0){
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
     if(empty($key)){
        /* do something */
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

btw. if you do

```
$fname = $_POST['name']
```

and the field isn't in the form you'll get

> Notice: Undefined index...

better use

```
$fname = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```